# How to hide my api key which is normally embedded in a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, api-key

I am building a small website using LiveScore api from rapidapi.com. How can I hide my api key when deploying my application. Tried .env method, serverless methods but didn't do much help. I am trying the api hiding method for the first time. Maybe that's why I am not getting it. Is there any method to hide api key which is fairly simple but a decent hiding?

//index.js

```
const options = {
method: 'GET',
headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'livescore6.p.rapidapi.com'
}
};

fetch('https://livescore6.p.rapidapi.com/matches/v2/list-by-date?   
Category=soccer&Date=20231801&Timezone=-7', options) 
.then(
response => {
    response.json().then(
        data => {
//my code here
})
```

Comment: Consider that even if a user can't (easily) find the source code with the key, they can still simply open the network tab and examine the network request itself, which still includes the API key. If the API key itself is not restricted to your application, then it just shouldn't be on the client-side.

Comment: look this https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In plain client side Javascript there is not much you can do to hide API Keys. I took a quick glance at the [RapidAPI docs](https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/consumer-quick-start-guide#integrating-the-api-into-an-application) and also this [blog post](https://rapidapi.com/blog/how-to-use-an-api-with-javascript/) from them, but they just use the API Keys as-is without securing anything. (lol)

So if you're worried about that information leaking, I would recommend you to create a **backend** in any backend language you prefer (it could be NodeJS, if you want to use Javascript) and use it as a proxy to make a request to that LiveScore API. If you do this you don't have to hardcode the API Keys in your client code, you could use `dotenv` in your backend, also you could control which endpoints to use and even add some custom basic authentication to be able to make a request.

This is a basic example using NodeJS and [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express):

```js
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get('/api/livescore', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': process.env.RAPID_API_KEY,
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': process.env.RAPID_API_HOST
      }
    };

    const rapidApiResponse = await fetch('https://some-rapid-api-endpoint.com', options);

    const parsedResponse = await rapidApiResponse.json();

    return res.json({ data: parsedResponse });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ err: err.message });
  }
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Comment: Just one thing to note: People can also simply use your backend API for their own purposes.

Comment: @CherryDT is correct. Creating your own server in order to protect the API key is indeed what should happen but then you also need to protect access to the server itself, otherwise anybody can just call up the endpoint and thus use the key without needing to know it.

Comment: @CherryDT Yep, as I pointed out in my answer you could secure it via basic authentication or auth with access tokens/refresh tokens